# Received error “Not Authorized to access this resource/api” when trying to use Google Directory API and OAuth2.0

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-api-python-client

I am working on a python script that creates a new google user in my domain and adds them to an existing group. To make sure everything was set up correctly, I wanted to first just list the current members of the group. Note that I have enabled the Admin-SDK API in the console & created an OAuth 2.0 credential. My code is as follows:

1. Authorize

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member']
creds = None
credsFile = os.path.abspath("pyScripts/googleCreds/credentials.json")
tokenFile = os.path.abspath("pyScripts/googleCreds/token.pickle")
if os.path.exists(tokenFile):
    with open(tokenFile, 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)

if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            credsFile, SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

    with open(tokenFile, 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)
```

2. Create user

```
service.users().insert(body=request).execute()
```

here request is a dict of parameters such as name & email, as required

3. List current members in group

```
service.members().list(groupKey='group@domain.com').execute()
```

The user is successfully created but I receive a 403 when trying to list the members of the group:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/group%40domain.com/members?alt=json returned "Not Authorized to access this resource/api">
```

What could be causing this issue? I'm particularly confused because the users endpoint works perfectly but the members one isn't working. I should also mention that I see the same behavior when using the API Explorer. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the same error code and message that you have.
This error 403 with "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" message will happen if you input an incorrect domain name in your group's email address.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members/list?hl=en

[image]

Comment: Hmm strange, I'm copy/pasting the group email directly from the "My Groups" tab in the console and still seeing a 403.

Comment: can you confirm if you are using a super admin account to add user and to view the groups member list? please verify if your account has an admin group privilege/role

Comment: You may also contact [workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) which can help you in your API issue encountered.